# Property is missing in type '{}' but required in type.... Typescript connect pattern

Tags: reactjs, typescript, redux

Hello I need connect pattern for react typescript

I have reducer

```
type State = {
  version: number,
  a?: string 
}


    interface ActionC {
      type: string
      payload?: number 
    }
    
    type IAction = ActionA | ActionB | ActionC;
    
    const reducer = (state: State = initialState, action: IAction) => {
      // The reducer normally looks at the action type field to decide what happens
      switch (action.type) {
        // Do something here based on the different types of actions
        default:
          // If this reducer doesn't recognize the action type, or doesn't
          // care about this specific action, return the existing state unchanged
          return state
      }
    }
```

but when I tying  use connect

```
export const App: FunctionComponent<{ version: number}> = (props) => {

    return (
      <div>APP {props.version}</div>
    )
    }



const mapStateToProps = (state: State) => {
  return {
    version: state.version
  }
};

export default connect(mapStateToProps)(App);
```

I have error

> Property 'version' is missing in type '{}' but required in type
> 'Omit<{ version: number; }, never>'.  TS2741

How to fix this problem ?

Comment: Unless you deliberately want to completely separate UI from state (there are good reasons for this), you can save yourself some pain and adopt the `useState` hook instead of using `connect`. Now you can do away with all the boilerplate of the `connect` HOC, and your component body looks like this  `const version = useState(state => state.version); return <div>{version}</div>`. Now that's much easier.

Comment: @spender i believe you mean `useSelector`, not `useState`

Comment: @NicholasTower Yes indeed. Thanks for the correction.

Answer (score 2):

As i pulled from https://redux.js.org/recipes/usage-with-typescript:

If you are still using connect, you should use the ConnectedProps type exported by @types/react-redux^7.1.2 to infer the types of the props from connect automatically. This requires splitting the connect(mapState, mapDispatch)(MyComponent) call into two parts:

```js
import { connect, ConnectedProps } from 'react-redux'

interface RootState {
  isOn: boolean
}

const mapState = (state: RootState) => ({
  isOn: state.isOn
})

const mapDispatch = {
  toggleOn: () => ({ type: 'TOGGLE_IS_ON' })
}

const connector = connect(mapState, mapDispatch)

// The inferred type will look like:
// {isOn: boolean, toggleOn: () => void}
type PropsFromRedux = ConnectedProps<typeof connector>

type Props = PropsFromRedux & {
  backgroundColor: string
}

const MyComponent = (props: Props) => (
  <div style={{ backgroundColor: props.backgroundColor }}>
    <button onClick={props.toggleOn}>
      Toggle is {props.isOn ? 'ON' : 'OFF'}
    </button>
  </div>
)

export default connector(MyComponent)
```

Answer (score 0):

Function connect must have 2 arguments, always. Even if you do not use mapDispatchToProps, you must pass it. While in JS null would do, in TS it should be an empty object.
So, your code should be

```
export default connect(mapStateToProps, {})(App);
```